# Error when trying to make an instance of a file manager

Tags: c#, file-manager

I am following a beginner tutorial on making a file manager and getting an error when trying to make an instance.

```
public class fileManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private static fileManager instance;    // Instance of the fileManager
    private string path;                    // Holds the application path

    public static fileManager Instance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new GameObject("fileManager").AddComponent();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }  
}
```

The error is :

> Expression denotes a type, where a variable, value or method group was expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to the GameObject constructor must be a variable, or one of those other things.  In particular, it must represent a value, that is, an instance of a type.  You have supplied the name of a type.

It is as though you wanted to open a file called C:\file.txt, but called `Open(string)` instead of `Open("C:\file.txt")`.

It might be a good idea to get in the habit of following .NET naming conventions, in which type names start with upper case letters.

Apparently, the tutorial's sample code is incorrect.  The GetComponent method requires either a type argument or a 'regular' argument.  The sample code supplies neither.

Comment: So you think when they made the tutorial they left something out? It is too bad everything else is explained so well.

Comment: An identifier that starts with a lower case letter is normally a variable, not a type name, so I would normally suspect that some confusion had arisen somewhere.  But you have it there loud and clear: public class fileManager....  Is the tutorial online?  I could have a quick look at it.

Comment: It is online. Thanks for taking the time to help. http://www.fizixstudios.com/labs/do/view/id/unity-file-management-and-xml

Comment: @JacobJones you forgot to put "fileManager" in quotes in that constructor call.  You are passing the class's name, not the class itself or an instance of the class. In other words, the value you pass must be a string.

Comment: Ah, ya I was trying different things. However, even with the quotes, I am getting the error "requires 1 type argument"

Comment: @JacobJones on which line, and what I'd the full text of the message?

Comment: instance = new GameObject("fileManager").AddComponent();____Using the generic method 'UnityEngine.GameObject.AddComponent<t>()'requires '1' type argument

Comment: @JacobJones try `GameObject("fileManager").AddComponent<fileManager>();`

Comment: @JacobJones you're welcome.  I added a brief explanation to my answer; you were right that something was omitted from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
instance = new GameObject(fileManager).AddComponent();
```

I'm guessing `GameObject` constructor expects a `Type` parameter.
Try changing to:

```
instance = new GameObject(typeof(fileManager)).AddComponent();
```

or:

```
instance = new GameObject(new fileManager()).AddComponent();
```

Comment: I tried both of your ideas but am getting a new error on top of the original now. I know it looks fishy, I am wondering if they just forgot to add something.